# unable to click on future date xdsoft control using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate xdsoft datepicker. Here is [datepicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) I am passing date which is 2 days ahead. Here is my code to select date

```
private void CLickOnDay(int day)
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> days = WrappedDriver.FindElements(
            By.CssSelector(".xdsoft_datepicker tr:nth-child(n+2) td:not(.xdsoft_disabled):not(.xdsoft_other_month) div"));

        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < days.Count; i++)
            {
                if (days.ElementAt(i).Text == day.ToString())
                {
                    days.ElementAt(i).Click();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException e)
        {
            throw e;

        }

    }
```

The variable days returns correct no of days in month but somehow it returns text as blank and hence it doesnt set any date.

Has anyone faced such issue? I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Post the relevant html.

Comment: @Guy its the same html as in link i provided

Comment: Did you try `GetAttribute("innerHTML")` or `GetAttribute("textContent")` instead of `Text`?

Comment: @Guy hey that works. Can you post it as answer with more explaination

Comment: You need to post the relevant HTML in the question. That link may go dead some day or the HTML may change, at that point this question becomes useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes selenium doesn't see an element as visible (you can verify if that's really the case here using `element.Displayed`). In that case `Text` property is an empty string by design.

To get the text in that case you can use `get_attribute()`

```
element.GetAttribute("innerHTML")
// or
element.GetAttribute("textContent")
```